# Alterar nome e sobrenome numa string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trabalho com uma API que me retorna o sobrenome primeiro depois o nome e eu preciso  o inverso como se lê o nome ( **no meu caso é um Autor de um Livro** ), o retorno que tenho é ( Ex.: Bragança, **Luiz Philippe De Orleans E** ) e eu preciso "**Luiz Philippe De Orleans E** Bragança", tentei fazer com reverse mas só funciona com Autores com 2 palavras.

```
string.Join(" ", Model.ItemInfo.ByLineInfo.Contributors[0].Name.Split(' ',',').Reverse())
```

Comment: Esse `name` vem `Bragança, Luiz Philippe De Orleans E`?

Comment: Olá Felipe, sim desta forma, e eu preciso como se lê o autor "Luiz Philippe De Orleans E Bragança"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você quer por a primeira palavra no final do que é retornado. Então, você pode:

```
public static string NomeAutor(string autor) {
    if(autor.Trim() == "") return "";
    string nomeCompletoRetornado = autor;
    string primeiroNome = nomeCompletoRetornado.Split(new char[] {' ', ','})[0].Trim();
    string resto = nomeCompletoRetornado.Substring(
         primeiroNome.Length + 1,
         nomeCompletoRetornado.Length - primeiroNome.Length - 1).Trim();
    string resultadoFinal = resto + " " + primeiroNome + ".";
    return resultadoFinal;
}
```

Uso:

```
NomeAutor("Bragança, Luiz Philippe De Orleans E") => "Luiz Philippe De Orleans E Bragança."
NomeAutor("José, Fino de Souza Pereira") => "Fino de Souza Pereira José."
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eZ7RGz).</sup>

Isso irá pegar o nome completo, obter o primeiro nome antes do `','` ou `' '`, remover do nome original o tamanho do que foi obtido do primeiro resultado e brevemente concatenar ele no final.

Comment: Não seria só o caso de fazer um split na vírgula e inverter as posições?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar dependendo da entrada, pode estar sendo dividido sem vírgula também. Pelo que entendi no código dele é isso, não faria sentido usar o `' '` e o `,`. Neste caso, se precisar dividir por espaços, iria dividir as outras palavras também.

Comment: Valeu @CypherPotato era exatamente isto, obrigado.